# Return type of recursive function

Tags: scala

What is the general type of `fs`?

```
 lazy val fs  = List(2,3,4).zip(fs.tail)
```

The compiler asks for setting it at compile time.

Update:
I wanted to consider a solution of the 2nd Project Euler problem:

```
    lazy val fs: Stream[Int] =
      0 #:: 1 #:: fs.zip(fs.tail).map(p => p._1 + p._2)

   fs.view.takeWhile(_ <= 4000000).filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum
```

I just wanted to debug what happens at these steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a most precise type that would describe it. Of course, it cannot be computed, so the actual type would be `Nothing`.

If we forget about the implicit canBuildFrom, the signature of zip in `List[A]` would be

```
def zip[B](l: List[B]) : List[(A,B)]
```

Starting with A = Int, it is clear that we have a `List[(Int, B)`], without even considering that the argument of `zip` is `fs.tail`. If we add that knowledge, we now have `List[(Int, (Int, B))]` and we can loop from there, you can type it `List[(Int,(Int, (Int, _)))]` and nest as many levels as you want.

I believe there is no way to express that most precise type (nesting to infinite) in scala. Anyway, it is not inhabited, this type contains no value, and fs cannot be computed.

Comment: @ZoltanHamori I'm not convinced this is true. See my answer.

Comment: I agree you cannot type it Nothing, and was aware of that (I had tried, should have mentioned it). I believe the reason is that while Nothing is a subtype of any type, there is no member you can call (which makes it a rather special subtype). I meant type Nothing as the type of something that will loop forever (or overflow the stack). I should have been more precise.

Comment: Yeah `Nothing` is special, but the reason it is impossible to type the result to `Nothing` is that the compiler requires a `List` and `Nothing` is not a `List` it has nothing (no pun intended ;) ) to do what the members of `Nothing` are.

Comment: I'm wrong on the 'member of Nothing' question. A simple workaround for that is `def zipLists[A,B](as: List[A], bs: List[B]) = as zip bs`, then you can call zip with a Nothing argument. That will not be enough to convince the compiler that fs has type Nothing. I would say that Nothing IS a List, but the problem is the over way round. Nothing is more than list, and a List is not a Nothing. You cannot prove to the compiler it is a Nothing.

Comment: I would still say that fs evaluates to type Nothing, (just as an expression may evaluate to a type more precise than what can be proved by the compiler), as its evaluation cannot be completed.  Haskell (no subtyping) complains that it "cannot construct infinite type b = (Integer, b)". I wonder whether this is enough to prove that the evaluation of the expression will diverge, which would be type Nothing in scala.

Comment: I see your point. When the collection used is `List` (as in the original question) I agree. The actual return type would be `Nothing`, but if we change it to a `Stream` then it is computable because of the lazy nature of a `Stream`

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles, but accessing `fs` generates a `StackOverflowError` because of the definitions recursize nature.

```
lazy val fs:List[Product] = List(2,3,4).zip(fs.tail)
```

If we wanted to be more specific about the type we could do something like:

```
lazy val fs:List[(Int, (Int, Product))] = List(2,3,4).zip(fs.tail)
```

The typle is not `Nothing`. Since the following does not compile:

```
scala> lazy val fs:Nothing = List(2,3,4).zip(fs.tail)
<console>:8: error: value tail is not a member of Nothing
   lazy val fs:Nothing = List(2,3,4).zip(fs.tail)
```

Similar type errors occur if we define fs as `List[Nothing]`,`List[(Int, Nothing)]` etc etc. So clearly the type of the expression is a `List` of `Product`. Now if we use `Stream` instead we can make something that does not cause a runtime error:

```
scala> lazy val fs:Stream[Any] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fs.zip(fs.tail).map(p => p:Any)
fs: Stream[Any] = <lazy>

scala> fs take 5 foreach println
0
1
(0,1)
(1,(0,1))
((0,1),(1,(0,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this possible in a type safe way, look:

```
scala> lazy val fs=List(1,2,3).zip(fs.tail)
<console>:7: error: recursive lazy value fs needs type
       lazy val fs=List(1,2,3).zip(fs.tail)
                                   ^

scala> lazy val fs:List[(Int,Int)]=List(1,2,3).zip(fs.tail)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Int, (Int, Int))]
 required: List[(Int, Int)]
       lazy val fs:List[(Int,Int)]=List(1,2,3).zip(fs.tail)
```

At least I can't see how to achieve any useful result. What is your intention?

On the other hand we can do this:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val fs = l.zip(l.tail)
fs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3))
```

Is it your desired result?